# GUI freezes in c# socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I have made a file receiving server in c# using socket programming. I have made a GUI . There is a  button named **'connect'** which will start the server on clicking it and there is a text box which will show a message when the server starts. But when I click on the button, the GUI freezes.

Here is my sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class sampleserver : Form
{

    private TextBox newText;
    public TcpClient tcpClient;
    public TcpListener tcpListener;
    public sampleserver()
{
    Text = " TCP Server";
    Size = new Size(400, 380);        
    newText = new TextBox();
    newText.Parent = this;
    newText.Size = new Size(200, 2 * Font.Height);
    newText.Location = new Point(10, 55);

    Button connect = new Button();
    connect.Parent = this;
    connect.Text = "Connect";
    connect.Location = new Point(295, 20);
    connect.Size = new Size(6 * Font.Height, 2 * Font.Height);
    connect.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonConnectOnClick);        

}


void ButtonConnectOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
    tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
    tcpListener.Start();
    newText.Text = "Server started"; //**This line is not working**

    //Infinite loop to connect to new clients      
    while (true)
    {
        // Accept a TcpClient      
        TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        string address = ((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();

                   byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
        int recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());

        // The first message from the client is the file size      
        string cmdFileSize = reader.ReadLine();


        int length = Convert.ToInt32(cmdFileSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
        int received = 0;
        int read = 0;
        int size = 1024;
        int remaining = 0;

        // Read bytes from the client using the length sent from the client      
        while (received < length)
        {
            remaining = length - received;
            if (remaining < size)
            {
                size = remaining;
            }

            read = tcpClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, received, size);
            received += read;
        }

    }

}
public static void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new sampleserver());
}
}
```

which change will I need to make to run this properly?

Comment: This is from a brief glimpse, which is why I am not answering your question. First, I would test the network code in a "console" application to make sure it works. I'm assuming your socket code works.  Offhand, your problem looks like a problem of 1) Launching network code, when usually UI buttons do something and then return. 2) I suggest that you have your button code launch a non-UI thread, and have that thread trigger event handlers to tell you when data arrives. 3) You'll have to stop the thread on exit, too.

Comment: `while(true)`... Thats your clue, you are blocking the UI thread by running an infinite loop, either spawn a new thread or use asynchronous programming.

Comment: I have tried to run the program by removing the infinite loop but same result @Ron Beyer

Comment: @user5379550 it will still block at this line: `TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();`, any blocking call will "lock up" the thread on which it is run.

Comment: I stick by my testing this as a console application and proving out the basic network code piece of it. When dealing with sockets -- and it's been 20 years -- there are timeout, synchronous, and asynchronous approaches to it.

Comment: yes.. still blocking at that line @Ron Beyer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use **Asynchronous sockets** but  you can also make only that button click method **Asynchronous** , simply like this.

```
async void ButtonConnectOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
tcpListener.Start();
newText.Text = "Server started"; //**This line is not working**
  await Task.Run(() =>
   {
//Infinite loop to connect to new clients      
while (true)
{
    // Accept a TcpClient      
    TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
    string address = ((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();

               byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
    int recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());

    // The first message from the client is the file size      
    string cmdFileSize = reader.ReadLine();


    int length = Convert.ToInt32(cmdFileSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    int received = 0;
    int read = 0;
    int size = 1024;
    int remaining = 0;

    // Read bytes from the client using the length sent from the client      
    while (received < length)
    {
        remaining = length - received;
        if (remaining < size)
        {
            size = remaining;
        }

        read = tcpClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, received, size);
        received += read;
    }

     }

 });
}
```

This would make the entire method asynchronous , and now you can read from the socket without freezing your main UI.

Goodluck.

Comment: To quote a comment i read recently, "you just showed him how to punch himself in the face". This isnt remotely the right way to go about it, what if someone double-clicks the button?

Comment: @Ashigore You can prevent double-clicking the button by disabling it on click, and then enabling it, if the launch failed. If launch succeeded, button stays disabled (greyed-out), and a second button stops everything.

Comment: getting the following error @Slashy
 "The name 'Task' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @user5379550 then you'll have to add the `System.Threading.Tasks` to your form. Goodluck. if i helped you i would very appreicate if you'll mark my answer :) thanks.

Comment: What is the main difference between the original code and your code @Slashy. Will you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

UI events usually are meant to run and then return. Your program is launching code that should be started in a thread -- by the button code -- and then properly stopped when the application exits.

As Ron Beyer stated, you have a `while(true)`, but I was more interested in whether the read times out or not and how you return to the main UI thread after the button is pushed. It looks like you never return to the main UI thread. As my comment stated, I'd test the network code, including the while loop in a console application, and then add on the complexities of a UI.

By the way, as other comments have pointed out, you cannot allow for a second click of your launch button, when you set up this code so the network setup (launch) succeeds. You'll have to disable (grey-out) the button, so it cannot be double-clicked, and only enabled if the network start (launch) failed. A second button, not greyed-out would allow you to shut everything down.

Threads and UIs are not the simplicity some would have you believe. They take quite a bit of work.

Comment: Typically the Windows "not responding" timeout is shorter than the network operations timeout, meaning Windows will throw up the not responding dialog before any network operation times out.